# Highchart's Polar Chart: Apply Gradient Color on Intersecting Area Series

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to apply gradient color at the intersecting area of 2 series in a Highchart's polar chart in my React project. Here's my JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/pgkk/s29d51zt/604/

The expectation is that:

1. Area within the marker should be of same color as the color of each marker.
2. Have the outline of the colored series, slightly bent at the ends like "spline/areaspline" as in the attachment.
   Could you please help me, thanks in advance.

```
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "chart": {
    "polar": true,
    "height": 190,
    "width": 290,
    "marginBottom": -25,
    "style": {
      "fontWeight": 400,
      "fontSize": 11,
      "letterSpacing": "-0.06px",
      "lineHeight": "16px"
    }
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "categories": [
      "Category1",
      "Category2",
      "Category3"
    ],
    "tickmarkPlacement": "on",
    "lineWidth": 0,
    "labels": {
      "useHTML": true,
      "align": "center",
      "style": {
        "whiteSpace": "nowrap",
        "color": "#26415e",
        "fontSize": "12px"
      }
    }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "gridLineInterpolation": "polygon",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 100,
    "showFirstLabel": false,
    "showLastLabel": true,
    "tickInterval": 25,
    "labels": {
      "align": "center",
      "y": 5,
      "x": 0,
      "style": {
        "color": "#333333",
        "fontSize": "10px"
      }
    }
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "marker": {
        "radius": 2.5
      },
      "states": {
        "hover": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "inactive": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "area": {
      "color": {
        "radialGradient": {
          "cx": 0.45,
          "cy": 0.5,
          "r": 1
        },
        "stops": [
          [
            0,
            "#DFA124"
          ],
          [
            0.25,
            "#AF9D3F"
          ],
          [
            0.5,
            "#5A9772"
          ],
          [
            1,
            "#229595"
          ]
        ]
      },
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": false
      },
    }
  },
  "series": [{
      "showInLegend": false,
      "data": [{
          "y": 100,
          "color": "#dce1e6"
        },
        {
          "y": 100,
          "color": "#dce1e6"
        },
        {
          "y": 100,
          "color": "#dce1e6"
        }
      ],
      "color": "transparent",
      "pointPlacement": "on",
      "marker": {
        "symbol": "circle"
      }
    },
    {
      "showInLegend": false,
      "data": [{
          "y": 36,
          "color": "#AF9D3F"
        },
        {
          "y": 64,
          "color": "#229595"
        },
        {
          "y": 33,
          "color": "#AF9D3F"
        }
      ],
      "pointPlacement": "on",
      "type": "area"
    }
  ]
});
```

[image: Expected Polar Chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use multiple area series with overlapping radial gradients.
2. You can overwrite `getConnectors` method and change the hard-coded `smoothing` value.

   ```
    H.Series.prototype.getConnectors = function(...) {
        var ...
            smoothing = 10, // 1.5 by defaults
            ...
        ...
    };
   ```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ob2xjkvs/

Comment: Thank you so much for responding back, the connector functionality works perfectly for smoothing the outlines of the graph.
I apologize for not being able to clearly explain the gradient question, as you see the chart has 4 polygons, each of them has a color associated with them. So, if marker falls within first polygon, the area around it is colored based on color of first polygon. Likewise, for remaining polygons too. By adding multiple series for gradient: https://jsfiddle.net/pgkk/s29d51zt/638/, 
Expected: https://jsfiddle.net/pgkk/s29d51zt/642/ (doesn't work for smaller graphs)

Comment: Hi @PGKK, No problem. So, it should only be a matter of the `radialGradient` settings. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lwzf4q3p/